# Why is Node-sass not compiling my scss into css in my Node/Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, sass

I'm extremely new to Node.js and Express.js. I want to be able to use SCSS instead of Stylus.

I've installed the node-sass to my node-modules and included it in my package.json file. And then I added the following code to my app.js file:

```
var sass = require('node-sass');
app.use(sass.middleware({
  src: __dirname + '/public',
  dest: __dirname + '/public',
  debug: true
}));
```

The problem is that nothing is compiling. I'm getting a 500 error in command line. See below

```
GET / 304 135ms
source : /Users/chrisdacie/Sites/express_example/public/stylesheets/base.scss
dest : /Users/chrisdacie/Sites/express_example/public/stylesheets/base.css
read : /Users/chrisdacie/Sites/express_example/public/stylesheets/base.css
...
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 4ms
undefined
GET /stylesheets/base.css 500 33ms
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I really don't want to use Stylus.

Comment: What is the content of base.scss

Comment: Essentially a series of prebuilt components from Wirefy https://github.com/cjdsie/wirefy/blob/master/sass/_base.scss

Comment: Same issue here with Bootstrap 3.1 Sass